# Why does iPad not fire onload events sometimes?

Tags: javascript, ipad, iframe, onload

I noticed on a web-app I was building that the jQuery `.load()` onload handler wasn't called *sometimes* (sometimes it worked, not sure what the cause was), when viewed on iPad. I even tried

`<iframe onload="alert(9)" ...`

to test it, and the alert didn't pop up. Is there a known bug or workaround for this? It was an iframe using [a workaround like this](http://dev.magnolia-cms.com/~czimmermann/blog/ipad-iframe/iframe1-tall.html), don't know if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Is the rest of your JavaScript code working on iPad?

JavaScript may be disabled in your Safari settings.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention it is happening intermittently. Just updated the question.

Comment: I'd have to conclude that sometimes Safari has a reason to think that the content hasn't completely loaded from the server, which makes the load event not fire. Have you tried document ready instead?

Comment: Also, have you tried this workaround: `$("#myIFrame").load(function (){
    alert("something");
});` – basically, just assigning id to the iFrame and selecting it with the id?

Comment: How would that be better than setting `onload="alert..."`? Why would changing the selector make load work?

Comment: First law of testing: when in doubt, follow best practices.

Comment: What do you mean? Iirc it fails to fire Jquery event when the onload attribute doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

iPad block js during scrolling...
Perhaps you begin to scroll before page actually load so 'load' woun't be triggered

But as I understand it should be triggered when scrolling stops...

it just an idea, hope it could be helpfull

Answer (score 0):

**I don't have a solution, but some amount of certainty as an answer:**

The jQuery team [had and has problems](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/#entry-longdesc), giving us a reliable .load() method,
that almost certainly means it is not reliable and there is no known workaround for it:

> - It doesn't work consistently nor reliably cross-browser
> - It doesn't fire correctly in WebKit if the image src is set to the same src as before
> - It doesn't correctly bubble up the DOM tree
> - Can cease to fire for images that already live in the browser's cache

found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12318079/444255