# iPad not updating page using javascript (with Django backend)

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ipad

I'm writing a script on a page that checks to see if specific parts of a page should update (based on information in the page passed in from the Django view).  The updating works on browsers on computers / notebooks, but fails on browsers on iPads (and, based on my reading, I expect iPhones).  It even works on my Pixel phone. So, it looks like this is a problem limited to iPads (and phones?).

At the moment, I am running on Django's dev server, if that has any bearing on the problem.  From what I can see on the putty terminal, the iPad is making the request (there's a GET every 2 seconds), but I don't know what's happening on the iPad that nothing is updating.  Both Safari and Chrome exhibit the same problem behavior.  Last time I looked at this problem (with slightly different code) it was NOT a problem for Macbooks, just iPads.

---EDIT---

I'm now running on a production server.  Still have the same problem.  Looking at the access logs, I can see the requests coming in from the iPad, just no changes to the displayed page.

---

Here is the code in question:

HTML

```
{% block page_updates %}
<div class="container-fluid" id="last_times">
    <p style="display:none">Last action taken: <span id="actionTime">{{ update_times.action.isoformat }}</span></p>
    <p style="display:none">Last chat made: <span id="chatTime">{{ update_times.chat.isoformat }}</span></p>
</div>
<p style="display:none">Page last updated: <span id="updateTime"></span>
{% endblock %}
```

Javascript

```
<script>
function refresh_action_log(){
    var url_actions = document.URL + ' #action_log';
    var url_destiny = document.URL + ' #destiny_box';
    $('#action_log').load(url_actions);
    $('#destiny_box').load(url_destiny);
}
function refresh_chat_log() {
    var url_chat_log = document.URL + ' #chat_log';
    $('#chat_log').load(url_chat_log);
}
function check_and_update() {
    var pageUpdate = new Date(document.getElementById('updateTime').innerHTML);
    var actionUpdate = new Date($("#actionTime").text());
    var chatUpdate = new Date($("#chatTime").text());
    var now = new Date();
    if (actionUpdate > pageUpdate && chatUpdate > pageUpdate) {
        refresh_action_log();
        refresh_chat_log();
        // changing all of the .toLocaleString() to .toISOString() was the solution
        document.getElementById('updateTime').innerHTML = now.toLocaleString();  
    } else if (actionUpdate > pageUpdate) {
        refresh_action_log();
        document.getElementById('updateTime').innerHTML = now.toLocaleString();
    } else if (chatUpdate > pageUpdate) {
        refresh_chat_log();
        document.getElementById('updateTime').innerHTML = now.toLocaleString();
    };
}
function update_times() {
    var url_last_times = document.URL + ' #last_times';
    $('#last_times').load(url_last_times, function () {
        // When it loads, schedule the next request for 2s later
        setTimeout(update_times, 2000)
    });
    check_and_update();
};
$(function () {
    update_times();
    var dt = new Date();  // This line and the next were sitting in another function
    document.getElementById('updateTime').innerHTML = dt.toLocaleString();
})
</script>
```

Based on some other stack overflow questions, I have a hunch the problem is caching in the iPad.

**Questions:**

1. Is this a caching problem?
2. If so, how do I tell iPads to handle it?
3. If not, what else should I be looking at?

---

EDIT:

Final solution: the iPad was reading the times incorrectly.  I'll post an answer that goes into detail.

Comment: Have you tried using a plain `$.ajax` call instead of `.load()`? [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12317987/load-does-not-work-on-ipad) question suggests that `.load()` might have issues in ipads.

Comment: @Jane Thanks but, the load in the question you link to is the old (deprecated) event ( http://api.jquery.com/load-event/ ), not the shortcut function ( http://api.jquery.com/load/ )

Comment: Ah I see now.  I figured that bug was probably outdated, but I didn't realize they were different methods all together.

Comment: Your server is getting code 200 from the requests from your ipad right?

Comment: @Jane yes to the code 200.  No errors logged at all.  (Although I am on the default error level.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, riddle me this, Batman: Why do iPads not handle date strings the same way as everything else?  After questioning everything (including my sanity), the problem was that, *on the iPad*, the Dates I was using to determine if the sections should be reloaded were invalid date types, while they worked just fine on everything else.

So, to answer my questions:

1. No
2. N/A
3. Time formatting.

The solution was to turn all of the .toLocaleString() into .toISOString().  For reasons unbeknownst to me, the iPad wasn't able to read the updateTime back in, parse it into a Date object and compare it to the other times when the code used .toLocaleString() (even though **all other** devices could.)

So, to reiterate, the iPad could not parse text from a Date object that had been put into .toLocaleString(), but it can if the text is in the ISOString format.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can have a race condition: if JavaScript code gets executed before the page is fully rendered, the first call to update_times() might miss $('#last_times'), and setTimeout() never gets triggered.

I suggest to postpone the call as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    update_times();
});
```

This ensures that update_times() runs once the page DOM is ready for JavaScript code to execute.

And maybe try to replace load() with ajax() to keep iPad happy, as suggested by Jane in a previous comment;
so use:

```
$.ajax( {
    url: url_actions,
    success: function(data) {
        $('#action_log').html(data);
    }
});
```

instead of:

```
$('#action_log').load(url_actions)
```

Comment: I'm sorry ... I noticed afterword you're using "$(function () {" as a shorthand for "$(document).ready(function() {" .. so please forget my previous response ;)
I would rather move the Javascript functions outside the "ready block", but I don't think that will solve your problem

Comment: covering my bases, so I moved the functions outside of the block.  no difference.  Thanks for the advice, though.

Comment: You're welcome ! BTW, did you try to replace load() with $.ajax() as suggested by Jane ?

Comment: I started to, but it is not a simple data swap out.  The sections (other than the timestamps) are very heavily processed by the html, so I think the ajax call is either going to be very complicated, or, I need to create a separate page per section that can do the heavy lifting, and then just grab that html and replace the divs.  I actually started down that path (separate pages) a bit, but ran into other problems with that solution.  I am rather new to javascripting, so it's entirely possible I have missed something simple.

Comment: Not at all: you're already doing an ajax call, although hidden by load(). So you won't need any particular refactoring, but rather a more explicit syntax. I'll update my reply above to give a code snippet, as no formatting is available in the comments

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet!  As I'm learning more about ajax, that's really useful.  But, if you see my answer, it turned out to be parsing a string into a Date object.  I updated my code to include the last two lines (that I had left out, not thinking they could be the problem).  var pageUpdate reads back in the date stamp of when the page was last updated, which is added by the code I added to my snippet.  The iPads I was testing on could not parse the string, while everything else could.  Had to find it by printing variables to the page, since Apple makes it so hard to debug.

Comment: Ohhh I see now .. glad you solved your problem ;) Thank you for discussion